# Applescript error: "Connection is invalid" when app quits

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm working on some code to check on the currently open tabs/windows in my installed web browsers, like so:

```
on checkbrowser()

    if application "Safari" is running then
        tell application "Safari"
            set windowList to (every window)
            # do some stuff
        end tell
    end if

end checkbrowser


repeat while 1 = 1
    checkbrowser()
end repeat
```

This works perfectly as long as Safari stays open. If Safari is ever closed while the script is running, I get this message:

> error "Safari got an error: Connection is invalid." number -609

The problem is something to do with `(every window)`. If Safari quits, shouldn't the `if` statement prevent the script from even going to that line of the code? But that is where it throws the error.

Any ideas? Thanks!

--
*Edit: Found the solution [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1513597).*

Comment: Please write up the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The key was to put the problematic code inside a `try` block. Like this:

```
    if application "Safari" is running then
        tell application "Safari"
            try
                set windowList to (every window)
                # do some stuff
            on error number -609
            end try
        end tell
    end if
```

This way, the script ignores the error -609 and just moves along, which is what I wanted.